# Increasing number of threads in OpenCL gives errors

Tags: c++, multithreading, kernel, opencl

I have an EC2 instance. It has a Tesla K80 GPU device. I am trying to run my OpenCL code on it where it makes use of heavy computations on the GPU. I am running into a very weird problem.

The problem is that I am sending the data to the device and then performing computations on it. If I set the number of threads 200, it works fine. But if I increase them to 400, I get "nan" errors on my computations.

**Here is how I call the kernel:**

```
kernelGA(cl::EnqueueArgs(queue[iter],
                    cl::NDRange(200 / numberOfDevices)),
                    d_value,
                    d_doubleParameters,
                    buf_half_population, and so on...)
```

The *numberOfDevices* here is 1.

**And here is the kernel code:**

```
__kernel void kernelGA (__global int * Parameters,
                          // other parameters etc. 
                         ) {
    int idx = get_global_id(0);

    if (idx != 0 && idx < POP_SIZE / numberOfDevices) {
      // Some computations using threads individually.
      if ((mutationRNBPercentage[(idx * chromosomeLength) + (deviceNumber * POP_SIZE * chromosomeLength / numberOfDevices) + j]) < transitionMutationPercentage) {
         // Apply some mutation to generate the next Individual.
         temp = temp + mutationRNBTransition[(idx * 3) + (deviceNumber * POP_SIZE * 3 / numberOfDevices) + j];

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      // Other heavy computations using threads individually.

    }
```

Also, if I increase the number of threads slowly from 200 to 240 to 280 and so on... it gives me no "nan" errors until I reach 440. At 440 threads, it gives me "nan" errors. Then when I try to track back to 400, it still gives me "nan" errors and it keeps on giving these errors till I reach back to 200. Then at 200, its fine.

PS: I had no problems and I never got such errors when I was running the same program on my MAC PRO.

Comment: does `queue[iter]` have same iter always or does it increase at each kernel execution?

Comment: It increases each time but of course it is related to the number of devices. Assuming that number of devices is always 1, it will just run only one time and not iterate.

Comment: whats the local range value?

Comment: I haven't set the local and global work sizes.

Comment: then its choosing local range auto, which can be only 1 when global range is divisible only by 1 and can be larger when its divisible by 20 40 or similar

Comment: So I just realized that between 200 and 1040 it doesn't work. But for more than 1040.. (even 4000 or 5000 works)

Comment: What is POP_SIZE value?

Comment: This is the value that defines the number of threads. When this value is between 200 and 1040, it DOES NOT WORK. But when the values is more than 1040, IT WORKS. Strange :/

Comment: You are using cl::NDRange as a kernel argument. Why don't you try with  a simple integer or an opencl-integer?